# Find the maximum number of consecutive hex digits from input

Tags: c++, hex

I am having trouble writing a program that reads a 64 bit unsigned long long in hex and finds the most frequent hex digit and returns how many times it occurs as well as the digit itself. 
Example,
input: 0xABCD_FFFF_43FF_42CF
output: Hex digit F occurred 4 times

So far here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 0;     
    char count = 0;
    char max = 0;
    char hexDigit = 0;
    unsigned long long x = 0xABCDFFFF43FF42CF;

    for ( i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        if (( x >> i ) & 0xF) // checking bits to see if they match previous hex digit
        {
            count++; // count increases if they are the same
        }
        else
        {
            count = 0;
        }

        if (count > max)
        {
            max = count;
         }
    }

    printf("Hex digit %x occured %d times\n", hexDigit, max);
}
```

I am not sure how to implement finding out which hex digit occurs the most so any help with what direction I can go is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remember that a hex digit is 4 bits.

Comment: There are only `16` hex digits (assuming conversion to upper/lower case if that is needed).   So set up an array of `16` integers, initialise them all to zero, and for each hex digit found, increment the appropriate array element.   When done reading, find the element of the array with maximum value.   If you are starting with an integral value, obtaining the hex digits is not that hard (use modulo `16` and dividing by `16` repeatedly).

Comment: I suggest that you turn off your computer and get a pen and paper. Write the steps **in words** you need to follow in order to solve this problem. It will help if you think about how you would do this by hand. Use Peter's suggestions above to help you get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char count = 0;
    char max = 0;
    char hexDigit = -1;
    char answer;
    unsigned long long x = 0xABCDFFFF43FF42CF;

    for ( i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        char curr = (x>>(4*i)) & 0xF;
        if (curr==hexDigit) // checking bits to see if they match previous hex digit
        {
            count++; // count increases if they are the same
        }
        else
        {
            count = 1;
            hexDigit = curr;
        }

        if (count > max)
        {
            max = count;
            answer=hexDigit;
         }
    }

    printf("Hex digit %x occured %d times\n", answer, max);
}
```

Comment: almost working. It is displaying a number 1 less than actual amount of occurences.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by it's displaying a number 1 less than actual amount of occurences ?

Comment: I'm sorry i had count = 0 in the else statement rather than 1. your answer works.

Comment: strange, in my compiler it show: Hex digit f occured 4 times
Press any key to continue . . . I'm using Dev-Cpp.